# Send multiple variables with PHP to AJAX over JSON doesnt work

Tags: php, ajax, json, post

I have a problem. I want to send 3-4 variables from a PHP File to my AJAX request (over json)... and I'm sure that my code is right, it doesn't work. It is doing nothing. If I'm doing just a normal "echo" everything works finde, but json is not working?

Here is my JS-code:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "test.php",
       data: "varA=" + varA + "&varB=" + varB,
       dataType: json,
       cache: false,
       success: function(data1){

       alert(data1.b);

       if (data1.a == "success"){
       alert("OK");

       location.href = "index.html";
       }

       else{
       alert("Not OK");
       }

       }
       });
```

And here is my PHP-code:

```
...
    $qry="SELECT * FROM database1 WHERE varA='".$_POST['varA']."' AND varB='".$_POST['varB']."'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $test = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo json_encode(array('a' => 'success', 'b' => $test['database_entry']));
...
```

I don't have a clue why this AJAX code would not be fired!
Hope you could help me, THANKS!

Comment: you data is not in the correct json format. it must be in name value pair

Comment: define "is not working" output the error message, also what did you debug with? Chrome inspector? firebug? etc;

Comment: I hope that you escape `$_POST['varA']` and `$_POST['varB']`! Please use `mysql_real_escape_string($str)` in order to prevent executing any SQL commands by a hacker.

Comment: @Jakub: it's doing nothing. i'm working in xcode, and with my debugging method it is not even going into the ajax-request.

Comment: @ComFreek: yes, thanks, I'm doing that. I declared a function which is doing that for me :)

Comment: Even better than the old `mysql_*` functions, either use `mysqli_*` or change to `PDO`, the old `mysql_*` functions are going to be deprecated, and they are more vulnerable than using `PDO`

Comment: @Rohit Kumar Choudhary: thanks, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are maiking a mistake by writing

`dataType: json,`

here json is supposed to be in a string

`dataType: 'json',`

In your code it is trying to search for the variable `json` which is not available and hence undefined, and hence no ajax call is made

Comment: maaaaaan (or woman), thanks. now it works like a charm. thank you!

Comment: man it is.
glad it helped..., please use firebug in firefox, chrome inspector where it clearly mentions what the error is.. and you can simply fix it... all the best for future prospects

Answer (score 2):

Send your data as a JSON object, not a self-generated query string:

```
data:  {"varA":  varA, "varB": varB},
dataType: json,
cache: false,
```

Comment: thanks. but that is also not working. is it in the php file possible to get the variables like $bla = $_POST['varA']; or should I do that in another way?

Answer (score 1):

The data you are sending to your ajax call is a string, wheras it should be an object or an array.

```
data: "varA=" + varA + "&varB=" + varB,
```

should be

```
data: {"varA":varA,"varB":varB},
```

Comment: thanks. but that is also not working. is it in the php file possible to get the variables like $bla = $_POST['varA']; or should I do that in another way?

Comment: try to `print_r($_REQUEST)` , to see if the variables pass in the first place.